# CloudFormation - IAM - Access Control with Tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have this requirement to create a role which can be used by developers. We only have a single account for Dev and Prod (Not recommended, I know).  The created resources are tagged with either dev or prod to identify the environments.  The requirement is that Developers can have ReadOnlyAccess on both environments but can only have full access on resources tagged with ***'dev'***

So if a developer wants to create a resource, he should tag it with dev.  Also, he can modify the other resources created by other users which are also tagged with dev.  From the AWS Documentation, I created a CloudFormation template with the snippet below but I noticed that only ReadOnlyAccess is allowed. The Developer could not create resources with 'dev' tag and cannot modify resources which already have the tag 'dev'.  Any pointers would be helpful.

I wanted to use PowerUseAccess which is a managed policy but unaware, how I could provide a condition on top of a managed policy.

```yaml
RoleDeveloper:
Type: AWS::IAM::Role
Properties:
  RoleName: DeveloperRole
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Version: 2012-10-17
    Statement: 
      - Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          AWS: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${UserAccountId}:root
        Action:
          - 'sts:AssumeRole'
  Path: /      
  Policies:
    - PolicyName: FullDeveloperAccessWithDevTag
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement: 
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: "*"
            Resource: "*"
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                aws:ResourceTag/env:
                  - dev
  ManagedPolicyArns:
    - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess
```

Comment: It is quite possible that the Condition will only apply to certain actions, since not all actions support conditions. Could you please tell us an example of what they tried to do, but were denied? Also, please tell us how they tried to perform the action (Console, AWS CLI command, API call) so that we can try to reproduce the situation.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Do you mean that wildcard for `Action` does not work with Condition? As an example, I could say DynamoDB. The developers were supposed to create a table with tag env: dev or modify a existing one with that tag without any difficulty. But that was not the case.  The access was using the Console.  Again, I used wildcard for `Action` because I am supposed to limit access to all resources for the Developers based on their tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wildcard isn't the problem. Rather, the issue is that not every API call will honor the Condition.

For example, `s3:ListBucket` doesn't take a tag as a condition. Nor does `dynamodb:ListTables`.

Also, while some commands (which I refer to as Actions) will accept conditions, they won't necessarily accept tags as Conditions.

Here is the documentation that shows Conditions for DynamoDB: [DynamoDB API Permissions: Actions, Resources, and Conditions Reference - Amazon DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/api-permissions-reference.html). I can't see any reference to tags.

However, tags are available as condition keys for Amazon EC2: [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for Amazon EC2 - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonec2.html)

Thus, some services and API calls simply can't be limited by tags.

Comment: Thank you. That made sense.